# How to add "name:" to existing javascript object/array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I really hope you can help me out. I'm retrieving some data from a webservice, I have it formatted already and put in an array, however I need the array to end up like this:

```
Phase = [
{"name": "start"},
{"name": "middle"},
{"name": "end"}
];
```

Right now I'm pretty sure it looks like this:

```
Phase{"start", "middle", "end"}
```

and i got it that way by using :

```
$.each(tempPhase, function(i, a){
if inArray(a, Phase === -1) Phase.push(a)});
```

but how do I add the "name": part to the push();?

I need the `.name` for a function of mine and I can't really change it to not use the .name because the function relies on 2 other arrays as well as this one

I am pretty sure its a rather simple operation, any help is appreciated.

///// THANKS EVERYONE FOR YOU HELP!! If i could mark both answers as best I would have because they are equally helpfull! :) ////

Comment: push `{ name : a }`, but that will break your check

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have an array of strings, and you want to convert it to an array of objects where each object has a property `name` set to the value of the original string. Is that right?

Comment: `Phase{"start", "middle", "end"}` this is not an array of strings, and it is not valid json either. Do you mean `["start", "middle", "end"]` ?

Comment: @JimCote: YES i am pretty sure that is what i mean

Comment: @melc well i cant really see it :D but if I output it i get start, middle, end (i added an ',' in the formatting)

Comment: @epascarello i am not sure what you mean by 'break your check'? :)

Comment: @epascarello also, it does not seem to work :)

Comment: In array will be looking at an object, not a string. It is `push({name:a})`

Comment: @epascarello actually this seemed to work - however now i just get a million of the same.. e.g: start start start start middle middle and so on - seems it forgot to check this time if its already ind the array... . oh thats what you meant.. but now how do i fix that? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create your own `inArray`, you have almost nothing to change.

```
function inArray(value, array)
{
    var vName = value.name;
    for(var i = array.length; i--;)
    {
        if(array[i].name == vName) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2fXJ7/

Or to be more general (if you need it to do something else):

```
function objectPropertyInArray(value, array, prop)
{
    var valProp = value[prop];
    for(var i = array.length; i--;)
    {
        if(array[i][prop] == valProp) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but could you please explain what happens in this code? :)

Comment: The first one (with the jsfiddle link) does what you seemed to want: it copies objects from tempPhase to Phase without copiyng two with the same "name" property. You can see the result in the console. The second one is an altered version of the previous `inArray` function, allowing you to check another property than the "name" one. So in your case if you want to use this one you have to do `if(!objectPropertyInArray(a, Phase, 'name'))`.

Comment: actually i can't see the result in the console - it does not print.. :/

Comment: That's strange. Here is a version that shows it in the result: http://jsfiddle.net/2fXJ7/1/

Comment: YES this worked.. does this make sure there is only one of each? :)

Comment: Yes, if `inArray` returns true we don't push it so each can't be pushed more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use js `map` function as follows,

```
var Phase = ["start", "middle", "end"]; 

Phase = Phase.map(function(elem){

    return {"name":elem};
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eA23j/

Comment: will this work if I dont 'fix' the array to begin with (i mean if someone later adds a Phase to the original xml it has to be retrieved automatically like the other stuff)

Comment: @Sally the `var Phase = ["start", "middle", "end"];` is just an example of your data. The rest regarding the `map` function is what you should use. I just assumed that you have an array of strings as you mentioned.

Comment: that is true - it is an array of strings - but retrieved from the webservice so the array might change if an admin decides to add a new phase :D  will this code check if the item is already in the array? :)

Comment: also - i cant seem to get the fiddle to run :/

Comment: @Sally Basically you can add any kind of logic inside the callback of `map` and  build a new array as required. The `map` will iterate through all the elements of your array and call the callback function for each one of them. However if you need to create a smaller array based on some logic then you better use `filter` as in `Phase.filter`.

Comment: @Sally it prints in the console of the browser. You can replace `console.log` with `alert` if you like, however from the console you can examine the result.